# Multi checkbox rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie with ReactJS. I am building a basic application which people can choose between two options for each day in the specified date range. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTF4S.png). I want to send the values of the checkboxes to API at  later stage. Maybe 100, maybe 500 I dont know how many checkbox will be.

I failed in several attempts. When clicking on checkbox, all list re-rendered. When there are 1000 checkboxes, re-rendering takes much time and 
browser was getting slow.

My question is, is it possible to render a single checkbox? If not, what should I do?

I am using Semantic UI React and it is my render function. Thanks in advance.

```
render() {
    return (
        <Table>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell></Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>{gettext('Choice A')}</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>{gettext('Choice B')}</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {this.state.datas.map((data, idx) => (
              <Table.Row key={idx}>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {data.date}
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {data.choiceA == false &&
                    <div>{gettext("-")}</div>
                  }
                  {data.choiceB == false && data.choiceA == true &&
                    <Checkbox defaultChecked readOnly/>
                  }
                  {data.choiceB == true && data.choiceA == true &&
                    <Checkbox/>
                  }
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {data.choiceB == false &&
                    <div>{gettext("-")}</div>
                  }
                  {data.choiceA == false && data.choiceB == true &&
                    <Checkbox defaultChecked readOnly/>
                  }
                  {data.choiceA == true && data.choiceB == true &&
                    <Checkbox/>
                  }
                </Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
              ))
              }
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
    );
  }
```

Data

```
[
 {'date': '19.03.2017', 'choiceA': False, 'choiceB': False},
 {'date': '20.03.2017', 'choiceA': True, 'choiceB': False},
 ...
]
```

Comment: hi, may I ask the format of the data you mapped on the table.

Comment: @kcneko I added this

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off using the `checked` prop from the semantic ui component:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/

I would simplify the code and render the checkboxes like this:

```
<Table.Cell>
     <Checkbox defaultChecked checked={data.choiceA} readOnly/>
</Table.Cell>
<Table.Cell>
     <Checkbox defaultChecked checked={data.choiceB} readOnly/>
</Table.Cell>
```

I suspect that all those conditional statements were/are causing performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have only been using React for about a year, but as I understand it, [React's virtual DOM](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom) should only look at the components that changed and render the change into the DOM.

Are you using event.preventDefault() with your handlers?